# get SVG file from wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, api, wikipedia-api

I am trying to work with the Wikipedia API in node.js. Is this possible to get only the [SVG file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Vector_images_of_trademarks) from Wikipedia API knowing only the category of those all images ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) API module as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) to get the list of images, and the [imageinfo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo) module to get the file URLs:

[action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category%3AVector+images+of+trademarks&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=imageinfo&generator=categorymembers&iiprop=url&gcmtitle=Category%3AVector+images+of+trademarks)